# when I import my module, why does it keep returning false?

Tags: python

I would really appreciate it if someone looked at my code and told me what i did wrong. The entire program is suppose to validate UPC-12, and ISBN-10 numbers. I created a module first, and then created a main program which i imported my module. We're not suppose to use "len" (length), or sub-strings. My main problem is that when the user enters a number in my main program, no matter if its UPC-12 or ISBN-10, it always returns false, meaning my program says "invalid"
Here is my module:

```
    # Gets the digit of the number using the specified position
def get_digit(number, position):
    return number / (10**position) % 10

def is_UPC12(number):
    sum_odd = 0
    sum_even = 0

    #loops through the UPC code and checks every odd position and adds the numbers
    for position in range(1, 12, 2):
        # calls the function
        get_digit(number, position)
        # gets the value
        odd_code = get_digit(number, position)

        sum_odd += odd_code 

    sum_odd *= 3

    #loops through the UPC code and checks every even position and adds the numbers
    for num in range(2, 12, 2):
        get_digit(number, position)
        even_code = get_digit(number, position)
        sum_even += even_code 

    total = sum_odd + sum_even
    total = total % 10 
    #subtracts 10 from the last digit of the sum, and if it's equal to the last digit of number then it returns True.
    if 10 - total == get_digit(number , 0):
        return True
    else:
        return False


def is_ISBN10(number):
    repeat = 1
    figure = 0

    for position in range(1, 10):
        # calls the function
        get_digit(number, position)
        # gets the value
        isbn_code = get_digit(number, position)

        figure = number * repeat
        repeat += 1

    total = figure % 11

    if total == get_digit(number , 0):
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

Here is my main program which imports my module:

```
import digitcheck2

def main():
    print "CHECK DIGIT VALIDATOR\n"
    print "What would you like to validate:\n"
    print "1. ISBN-10"
    print "2. UPC-12"
    print "Q. Quit Program\n"

    quit = False
    while quit == False:
        choice = raw_input("Which one?: ")

        if choice == "1":
            ISBN_Valid()
        elif choice == "2":
            UPC_Valid()
        elif choice == "Q" or choice == "q":
            quit = True

def ISBN_Valid():
    num = input("Please enter a ISBN-10 number: ")
    if digitcheck2.is_ISBN10(num) == True:
        print "Valid ISBN-10 code.\n"
    elif digitcheck2.is_ISBN10(num) == False:
        print "Invalid ISBN-10 code.\n"    

def UPC_Valid():
    number = input("Please enter a UPC-12 number: ")
    if digitcheck2.is_UPC12(number) == True:
        print "Valid UPC-12 code.\n"
    elif digitcheck2.is_UPC12(number) == False:
        print "Invalid UPC-12 code.\n"   

main()
```

Comment: Can you provide two valid values, one for ISBN10 and one for UPC12?

Comment: A debugger would help you out here. Otherwise, the most basic option is to inspect the value of things throughout the script using print statements.

Comment: a valid value for UPC12 is 12345678905 and a valid on for ISBN10 is 130417173

Comment: BTW, you can just have "return 10 - total == get_digit(number , 0)". That creates a boolen anyway, so no need to check the boolean then explicitly return a boolean.

Answer (score 1):

The first problem I see is with the `get_digit` function: it doesn't do what it is supposed to. Now, rather than fixing the math, I am going to simply make an alternate version with `str` and `int`, which can obviously be further optimized:

```
# Gets the digit of the number using the specified position
# position is 1-based
def get_digit(number, position):
    return int(str(number)[position-1])
```

This fixes the results for `is_UPC12`.

As for `is_ISBN10`, there is a suspicious path in there, where variable `isbn_code` is not used, and a pretty much useless call to `get_digit()` before that, so we should revisit the code.

Per ISBN10, the calculation for a number like `abcdefghij` should be something like:

```
j = ( [a b c d e f g h i] * [1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9] ) mod 11
```

So I rewrote the function as:

```
def is_ISBN10(number):
    z = zip(map(int, str(number)), range(1,10))

    total = sum(x * y for x, y in z)
    parity = total%11

    print parity, get_digit(number, 10)
    return parity == get_digit(number, 10)
```

While it uses some more sophisticated python constructs, it should still be readable enough. This validates a UPC10 value.

Note that the value `130417173` in the comment doesn't seem to the UPC10, being only 9 digits.

Comment: You don't need the list comp in `map(int, [x for x in str(number)])`. You can map over a string: `map(int, str(number))`.

Comment: Also `sum` takes an iterable. Give it a generator expression: `sum(x * y for x, y in z)`.